# Map abstract class to DTO with MapStruct

Tags: java, mapping, dto, mapstruct, java-ee-8

I found a lot of topics to this but all solutions went into a wrong direction in my eyes.

So... How do i use MapStruct mapping for this case?

abstract class Person:

```
public abstract class Person implements Serializable{

     private String name;
     private String somethingToIgnore

     //Getter and Setter

}
```

The normal Mapper doesn´t work:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = 'cdi')
public interface PersonMapper{

    @Mapping(target = 'somethingToIgnore', ignore = 'true')
    Person toPerson(PersonDTO source);

    @InheritInverseConfiguration
    PersonDTO toPersonDtO(Person source);

}
```

I am not allowed to map an abstract class. I should use the a factory method. I tried but i simply have no clue how this factoy method should look like...

My attempt:

```
@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {

    PersonMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( PersonMapper.class );

    Person toPerson(PersonDTO source);

    PersonDTO toPersonDtO(Person source);
}
```

```
@Mapper
public abstract class PersonMapper {

    public static final PersonMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper( PersonMapper.class );

    Person toPerson(PersonDTO source);

    PersonDTO toPersonDtO(Person source);
}
```

What am i missing and doing wrong ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

MapStruct doesn't know how to map to abstract class, because it cannot instantiate it. I expect that you have some implementation of `Person`. You need to provide method which will create object of a `Person` like this:

```java
@Mapper
public interface PersonMapper {

    Person toPerson(PersonDTO source);

    PersonDTO toPersonDtO(Person source);

    default Person createPerson() {
        return new PersonImpl();
    }
}
```

This way MapStruct will use this method to create `Person` instance and than map the properties like usual. You can find more about object factories in [the documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#object-factories).

Comment: I did another horrible mistake. Your Answer is already helping me. I will test it next week and report. ty

Comment: I had another mistake.. my question wasn really correct but anyway i will mark you answer right cause it is right.

Comment: @Tuom Is there any chance I can have a dto as an argument for the method createPerson() ?

Comment: @Julien, one way which comes to my mind is using [`@Context`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#passing-context). Something like this: `Person toPerson(PersonDTO source, @Context PersonDTO context);`, `default Person createPerson(@Context PersonDTO context)`.

Comment: @Julien, and if you don't want to put the same object as an argument two times, you can overload `toPerson` method like this:
`default Person toPerson(PersonDTO source) { return toPerson(source, source); }`

Comment: @Tuom Thank you. I just found a solution by upgrading the mapstruct version and then use \@ObjectFactory default Person toPerson(PersonDTO source) {...}

Comment: @Julien Nice. I didn't know that it works this way. Good to know.

Comment: @Julien Could you put the solution in a comment, please?

Comment: And when you have different subClasses? It's a mapper to json which is a dynamic format and it's widely popularized, it should be able to know it. ModelMapper could do it.